# Is it possible to set spring security session expiration by age?

Tags: spring-security, session-timeout

I am trying to get a spring security session to expire after 30 minutes from log in. I do not want the timeBeforeExperation to be reset after every interaction.

Current Configuration:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible with standard spring security.